# Leibniz rule bound for the inverse of the Laplacian?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, sp.spectral-theory

Let $f, g \in L^2[\mathbb{T}^2]$ be real-valued functions without zero modes. That is, $\int_{\mathbb{T}^2}f=\int_{\mathbb{T}^2}g=0$. Here, ${\mathbb{T}^2}$ is the $2$-dimensional torus $[\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}]^2$.

Now, consider the quantity
\begin{equation}
(-\Delta)^{-3}\Bigl[ fg- \int_{\mathbb{T}^2} fg \Bigr] \in W^{6,1}[\mathbb{T}^2]
\end{equation}

Then I wonder if it is possible to find positive constants $C_i$'s independent of $f,g$ such that
\begin{equation}
\Bigl \lVert (-\Delta)^{-3}\Bigl[ fg- \int_{\mathbb{T}^2} fg \Bigr] \Bigr \rVert_1 \leq \sum_{i=0}^3 C_i\lVert \Delta^{-3+i} f \rVert_2 \lVert \Delta^{-i} g \rVert_2 
\end{equation}

I tried to use the Fourier expansion, but the product turns into convolution and things seem to get tricky...All references I looked for deal only with the Leibniz rule for the fractional Laplacian of positive exponent.

Could anyone help me with the negative exponent case?

Comment: It is hopeless even on $\mathbb T$ and for $(-\Delta)^{-1}$. Take $f,g$ with Fourier coefficients $1/\sqrt{N}$ on $[-2N,-N]\cup[N,2N]$ and $0$ elsewhere. Their $L^2$ norms are about $1$ but the $L^2$-norm of their inverse Laplacians are like $N^{-2}$. However the product $fg$ has Fourier coefficients of size $1$ on the entire interval $[-N/2,N/2]$, say, so just killing the zeroth Fourier coefficient will not bring the $L^1$ (or any other) norm of $(-\Delta)^{-1}(fg)$ down.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. At least isn't  it true that the zeroth mode of the Fourier expansion must be eliminated if we want to act on the inverse Laplacian?

Comment: Of course, that is true. The point is that it still doesn't help much...

Comment: Yes I just wanted to check for sure. Thank you.